# java.lang.NullPointerException while running Springboot application for Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to run Springboot application but getting below error. I tried to search for this error but couldn't get the exact resolution. As this is a Kafka consumer application, I am hoping to get the records from the consumed topic. But, the application is failing at the first step only but I am not only to figure out the issue. As I am new to Springboot, any suggestions for debugging would be appreciated.

**Error :**

```
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:22.278[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.example.consumer.ApplicationRun     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting ApplicationRun on LHTU05CD9032TMM with PID 36708 (C:\Users\psingh69\IdeaProjects\KafkaSpecificAvroConsumer\target\classes started by psingh69 in C:\Users\psingh69\IdeaProjects\KafkaSpecificAvroConsumer)
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:22.287[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.example.consumer.ApplicationRun     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:22.386[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:22.386[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:25.300[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:25.341[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:25.342[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:26.199[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:26.199[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.web.context.ContextLoader           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:26.199[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.web.context.ContextLoader           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3813 ms
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:26.845[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mf.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: static com.example.consumer.PayConsumer com.example.consumer.ApplicationRun.payConsumer
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:26.945[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Patterns [/**/favicon.ico] in 'faviconHandlerMapping'
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:27.249[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:27.269[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:27.363[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 2 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:27.402[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:27.418[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:27.884[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m LiveReload server is running on port 35729
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:27.894[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:28.025[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2020-07-03 18:07:28.032[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m36708[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.example.consumer.ApplicationRun     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started ApplicationRun in 6.579 seconds (JVM running for 10.534)
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.consumer.ApplicationRun.main(ApplicationRun.java:19)
    ... 5 more
```

**Application.java :**

```
package com.example.consumer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationRun {
    
    
    @Autowired
    static PayConsumer payConsumer;

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRun.class, args);
        
        payConsumer.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your PayConsumer is static because you want to use it in the main method, but it cannot work like that. You could refactor your code to implement CommandLineRunner and implement the run method. Then you'll be able to use your non-static injected payConsumer bean.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me !!

```
package com.example.consumer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationRun {
    
    
    @Autowired
    static PayConsumer payConsumer;
    
    public ApplicationRun(PayConsumer payConsumer) {
        ApplicationRun.payConsumer=payConsumer;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRun.class, args);
        
        
        
        payConsumer.run();
    }
}
```